# What is the new version of `componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps, nextContext)`?

Tags: react-context, react-lifecycle

I'm using this lifecycle method `componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps, nextContext)`, but I'm aware that this is a legacy method. I tried to refactor it with `static getDerivedStateFromProps(nextProps, nextContext)`, and find out that I can't access the `context`.

So my question is what is the new way to pass `props` and `context` to update the component?